Azure Data Studio Build error SQL70001: This statement is not recognized in this context
Im using the Azure Data Studio to build an .sqlproj which later on I use it it in order to build and deploy a .dacpac file via Azure Pipelines to a Azure Database (SQL Server).
I'm creating user, roles, permissions .... Everything was going smoothly.
At some point I created a folder xxxxx and created an .sql file in it.
The file is basically empty:
PRINT '-----------'

From this point on when building the database project, I started receiving a

Build error SQL70001: This statement is not recognized in this context.

error which makes zero sense to me.
I probably changed something in between.
But the error itself is not self-explanatory at all
The .sqlproj contains the line which points to the location where the .sql file is:
<ItemGroup>
    ...
    <Folder Include="xxxx" />
    ...
</ItemGroup>

What even context mean? To what context does it refer to?
Any ideas on what it can go wrong?

When I leave the .sql file empty, it builds properly which is odd
